# Getting UnAuthorized 403 Error For Azure FHIR API

Tags: azure, fhir-server-for-azure

I'm using Azure FHIR API,  Created and FHIR API, Registered an Client Application and added Azure Health Care APIS as well data fhir contributor role for my user, Trying to access this FHIR API via postman,  Im able to generate bearer token via client credentials, On passing this valid credentials to access FHIR im getting below error

{

"resourceType": "OperationOutcome",

"id": "8260291545643a43917c9ec116eb0b9d",

"meta": {

"lastUpdated": "2022-03-11T04:59:59.6007935+00:00"

},

"issue": [

{

"severity": "error",

"code": "forbidden",

"diagnostics": "Authorization failed."

}

]

Answer (score 0):

To access the FHIR service, you will also need to provide the client app an application role, such as "FHIR Data Contributor." Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir/configure-azure-rbac-for-fhir for more information.